# AWS Elasticsearch Snapshots - IAM issue because of service-linked role

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

I'm trying to get manual snapshots setup for my AWS Elasticsearch cluster.  I'm not sure how to setup the correct IAM permissions on the S3 bucket though because there is already a service-role created and I'm unable to add additional policies.

What am I supposed to do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by creating a second IAM role using the CLI (it doesn't seem to be an option through the GUI)